# Bypass Task Scheduler is not working. Any Idea or Trick?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have Powershell 2.0 and Windows 7 in two machines. 
Im admin of one but the other has some security restrictions.

Learning in google, i found the next code:

```
$hour24 = (Get-Date).ToString("HH:00")
& schtasks /create /tn MyBATScheduledTask /sc HOURLY /mo 1 /ST ${hour24} /f /ru SYSTEM /tr "C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\MyBat.bat"
```

That works using Admin rights, but when i try on the second machine gets: 
"Access Denied"

I played with other codes also but nothing usefull.

There is a secret? There is possible?

Comment: Drop the braces, `${hour24}` => `$hour24`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no a PowerShell code issue.

Many configs in Windows require you be admin on the box. So, ***if admin is required by Windows, then admin must be used in the PowerShell session.***

Also, that command as written is not really correct. Quoting matters when running external commands / executables.

[PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

> 5. The Call Operator &
>
> Why: Used to treat a string as a SINGLE command. Useful for dealing
>   with spaces.
>
> In PowerShell V2.0, if you are running 7z.exe (7-Zip.exe) or another
>   command that starts with a number, you have to use the command
>   invocation operator &.
>
> The PowerShell V3.0 parser do it now smarter, in this case you don’t
>   need the & anymore .
>
> Details: Runs a command, script, or script block. The call operator,
>   also known as the "invocation operator," lets you run commands that
>   are stored in variables and represented by strings. Because the call
>   operator does not parse the command, it cannot interpret command
>   parameters
>
> Example:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' "c:\videos\my home video.avi" /fullscreen
```

> Things can get tricky when an external command has a lot of parameters
>   or there are spaces in the arguments or paths!
>
> With spaces you have to nest Quotation marks and the result it is not
>   always clear!
>
> In this case it is better to separate everything like so:

```
$CMD = 'SuperApp.exe'
$arg1 = 'filename1'
$arg2 = '-someswitch'
$arg3 = 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt'
$arg4 = '-yetanotherswitch'

& $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4

# or same like that:

$AllArgs = @('filename1', '-someswitch', 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt', '-yetanotherswitch')

& 'SuperApp.exe' $AllArgs
```